# Reversi VB.net logic behind it

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make the reversi game in VB.Net. I have some difficulties translating the game`s logic into vb.net

If a button is black and the button next to it is white,than  the button next to the white one will be black wen pressed.

```
    newButton.tag = colum of button + (row of button * amount of columns)
    -> I made 64 buttons via a function loop and added a tag 


    Dim knop As Button = sender
    Dim value As String = knop.Tag
    If value = "...(?)" Then
        knop.BackColor = Color.Black
       If ....(?)
       End If
    End If
```

I already made  a scheme with the label of the buttons, but I find it hard to implement the logic. Can someone help me out with thid one?

EDIT:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gdrJ.png

Comment: not everyone knows the rules for reversi.  `the button next to it` is not at all clear since there are 4 buttons around those in the center, 8 if you include diagonals.  once you define the question clearly in your own mind, the logic might become clear

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Dim ButtonList As List(Of List(Of Button))` and add the buttons to the form in runtime you can add each the button for each row to a list then add that list to ButtonList.  Now you can access each button by the indexes in the 2 dimensional list.

Since you're changing the backcolor just use that instead of using the tag.